# How to sort and create hash string using LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, java-8, jackson, jackson-databind, linkedhashmap

I am developing an application within that I have to create the SHA256 hash for the incoming data. To make that I have to follow the specific sorting order for each property. Hence, I have created a class `TemplateNodeMap` which extends `LinkedHashMap`, within that I have specified the order that I need to follow.

Now, I would like to read each property in the incoming JSON data, add a specific field, and create the Hash string. I am a bit confused about adding the data and creating the string. I am worried if I am following the optimal procedure or not as I need to follow the process for a large amount of data.

Can someone please let me know if this is the right approach?

Following is the incoming JSON (Since JSON can have any order I need to obtain properties according to my required Hash String order):

```
{
  "age": 30,
  "name": "Batman",
  "address": {
    "city": "Gotham",
    "street": {
      "name": "Gotham 123"
    }
  }
}
```

Following is my `TemplateNodeMap` class:

```
package io.hash;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class TemplateNodeMap extends LinkedHashMap {
    public TemplateNodeMap() {
        put("name", null);
        
        put("age", null);
        
        put("address", new LinkedHashMap<>() {{
            put("street", new LinkedHashMap<>() {{
                put("name", null);
                
            }});
            
             put("city", null);
        }});
    }
}
```

Following is my `ApplicationMain` class which is reading and loading the data to `TemplateNodeMap`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ApplicationMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final InputStream jsonStream = ApplicationMain.class.getResourceAsStream("/InputJSON.json");
        final ObjectNode inputTemplate = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStream, ObjectNode.class);
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(inputTemplate));
        final TemplateNodeMap templateNodeMap = new TemplateNodeMap();
        templateNodeMap.put("name", inputTemplate.get("name"));
        templateNodeMap.put("age", inputTemplate.get("age"));
        //Unable to understand how to insert the complex object values into LinkedHashMap and follow the order
    }
}
```

1. I am not understanding how to add the complex object to LinkedHashMap and create a string out of it.
2. Not all fields are mandatory so I would like to omit the null values during the creation of Hash String.

Can someone please suggest to me how to achieve this and if this is the right approach to creating a Hash String based on the required order?

Comment: `Map<?, ?> map = objectMapper.readValue(inputJson, Map.class);` would already give you a filled LinkedHashMap instance. You then only need to take care of constructing the sorted string from it (while ignoring null elements).

Comment: NON_NULL can also be applied to the object mapper, see https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-ignore-null-and-empty-fields

`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);`

Answer (score 0):

Requirements:

- "I am developing an application within that I have to create the SHA256 hash for the incoming data."
- "To make that I have to follow the specific sorting order for each property."

Proposal:

- Create data classes for your incoming data, order their attributes as you like
- Transform data class into a 'standard' JSON representation using prettyprint
- Calculate hash over 'standard' JSON representation
- For completeness a manual parsing of the linked hashmap is included

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.*;

class Person {
    int age; String name; Address address; // Attribute order effects output order!

    public Person(){}
    public Person(int age, String name, Address address) {
        this.age = age; this.address = address; this.name = name;
    }
    public void setAge(int age){this.age = age;}
    public int getAge(){return age;}
    public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
    public String getName(){return name;}
    public void setAddress(Address address){this.address = address;}
    public Address getAddress(){return address;}
}

class Address {
    String city;
    Street street;
    public Address(){}
    public Address(String city, Street street){this.city = city; this.street = street;}
    public void setCity(String city){this.city = city;}
    public String getCity(){return city;}
    public void setStreet(Street street){this.street = street;}
    public Street getStreet(){return street;}
}

class Street {
    String name;
    public Street(){}
    public Street(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public String getName(){return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
}

public class ApplicationMain {
    static String inputJson = "{\"age\": 30,\"name\": \"Batman\",\"address\": {\"city\": \"Gotham\",\"street\": {\"name\": \"Gotham 123\"}}}";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            // use Paths.get("InputJSON.json").toFile() as alternative to the string
            Map<?, ?> map = objectMapper.readValue(inputJson, Map.class);
            System.out.println("The linked hashmap to process for sorting:");
            System.out.println(map);

            System.out.println("Individual elements:");
            System.out.println("name: " + map.get("name"));
            System.out.println("age: " + map.get("age"));
            System.out.println("address:");
            Map<?, ?> addressMap = (Map<?, ?>)map.get("address");
            System.out.println("    city: " + addressMap.get("city"));
            System.out.println("    street:");
            System.out.println("        name: " + ((Map<?, ?>)addressMap.get("street")).get("name"));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Person person = objectMapper.readValue(inputJson, Person.class);
        System.out.println("Original JSON:\n" + inputJson);
        String prettyJson = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(person);
        System.out.println("Standardized JSON:\n" + prettyJson);

        byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(prettyJson.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        for ( byte b : hash) {
            System.out.printf("%02x", b);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

```
$ java -cp .:jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:jackson-core-2.13.3.jar:jackson-annotations-2.13.3.jar ApplicationMain
The linked hashmap to process for sorting:
{age=30, name=Batman, address={city=Gotham, street={name=Gotham 123}}}
Individual elements:
name: Batman
age: 30
address:
    city: Gotham
    street:
        name: Gotham 123
Original JSON:
{"age": 30,"name": "Batman","address": {"city": "Gotham","street": {"name": "Gotham 123"}}}
Standardized JSON:
{
  "age" : 30,
  "name" : "Batman",
  "address" : {
    "city" : "Gotham",
    "street" : {
      "name" : "Gotham 123"
    }
  }
}
5f962abf0cdc5150eb2614c629592d889d59b82499b13dd1b8d12e421bb0440a
$
```

You can check the hash value at [https://dencode.com/hash](https://dencode.com/hash?v=%7B%0A%20%20%22age%22%20%3A%2030%2C%0A%20%20%22name%22%20%3A%20%22Batman%22%2C%0A%20%20%22address%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22city%22%20%3A%20%22Gotham%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22street%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%20%3A%20%22Gotham%20123%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&oe=UTF-8&nl=lf)
(The link already contains the JSON data. If you paste text there, verify that the correct line ending type is selected.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two jackson annotations that can help you to serialize the jackson properties in a custom order excluding the non null values:

- [`JsonPropertyOrder`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html) annotation that can be used to define ordering (possibly partial) to use when serializing object properties.
- [`JsonInclude`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html) annotation used to indicate when value of the annotated property, or all properties of the annotated class, is to be serialized.

You can then deserialize your json to the pojo java classes and then serialize them obtaining a new json with the expected order of the properties and without null properties:

```
@Data
@JsonPropertyOrder(value = {"name", "age", "address"})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Person {
    private int age; 
    private String name;
    private Address address;
}

@Data
@JsonPropertyOrder(value = {"street", "city"})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Address {
    private String city;
    private Street street;
}

@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Street {
    private String name;
}

//you can delete for example the name property from your json
Person person = mapper.readValue(json, Person.class);
String output = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(person);
//ok, the name property will not appear in the output because it's null
System.out.println(output);
```